# Trying to create anchor link

Tags: html, navigation

I am trying to create a basic anchor link within the same page. I am using Bootstrap 4 (whether that makes a difference or not). The link and the target are both in server-side includes. I want to link from the upper nav "Contact" to the form I have in the footer.

In the "upperNav" include I have the following:

```
<a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="#contactMe">Contact</a>
```

In the "footer" include I have the following:

```
<p class="contactUs"><a id="#contactMe">Contact Us</a></p>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I have researched this problem but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
<!--   From: https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap4/demo2.php?ex=91.0_8   -->
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-info ">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-light logo-text" href="http://shamar.org/" >shamar.org</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo-navbar" aria-controls="demo-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="demo-navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="/index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="/articles/index.html">Articles</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="/weblog/">Blog</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="/books.html">Books</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="/multimedia/index.html">Multimedia</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="/about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-light main-menu" href="#contactMe">Contact</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light submit2 my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included all the code for the navbar and remove any custom class names for testing purposes as people can't see your CSS.

Comment: Is that better? It's on a local dev computer right now. Is anything else needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<a id="#contactMe">Contact Us</a>
```

To

```
<a id="contactMe">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Ah! That's it! I knew it was something simple. Thanks!